# C++ Storing class objects in vector; pulling them back returns gibberish

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, object, vector

In my C++ program I am pulling rows back from an SQL database, and then want to maintain a vector of objects representing the rows. This is my exact code with just the object names changed:

```
vector<Foo> vFoos;
vFoos.clear();

for (int i = 0; i < sql.GetCount(); i++) {
    Foo foo;
    foo.nID = atoi(sql.GetItem(_T("id"),i);
        trace.Output(foo.nID);
    foo.strName = sql.GetItem(_T("name"),i);
        trace.Output(foo.strName);
    vFoos.push_back(foo);
}

for (long l = 0; l < vFoos.size(); l++) {
    trace.Output(vFoos[l].nID); 
    trace.Output(vFoos[l].strName);
}
```

As you can see, to confirm that this has worked, I am immediately, within the same method, reading back the object using my trace class (which outputs to a file for debugging). The traces off of the foo object in the first loop always reads back fine, so we are pushing an entirely vaild Foo object into the vFoos vector. However, in the second loop, the trace output returns a blank value for the strName property and a random 10-digit number (e.g. 1729384768, 972536489, -2617384908) for nID.

Does anyone have a clue why it is doing this? My understanding was that push_back()ing an object into a vector like that creates a copy of the object, so it should read back fine?

Ta!

Comment: How do you implement the copy constructor for `Foo`?

Comment: Also, what are the types of `nID` and `strName`?

Comment: Probably the copy constructor of `Foo` is broken

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the vector? Also, what does `Foo` look like?

Comment: Ok, so I wasn't aware of the concept of a "copy constructor" (still reasonably new to C++), so I just researched it and implemented one. It works fine now. Feel so stupid.. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you should not use atoi() here. atoi() returns 0 when the input cannot be interpreted as an integer number - which means that you cannot distinguish between real 0 (i.e. "0") and an error (e.g. "abc"). Consider using the new C++11 conversion functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol